# How can I do an UPDATE without a "bind_param"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I'm trying to set up a simple attendance web app for my company. The check-in/out is done with one button and in order to do that I'm doing an INSERT and an UPDATE almost at the same time. 
But to do a proper UPDATE I need an 'id' for the 'bind_param', and I'm kinda stuck there. I bet that it's a simple problem, but I can't find my way around it.

```php
if ($pre == 0) {
    $sql = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO presence(code_pr,heure_debut,user_id)
        VALUES( ? , ? , ? )
        ") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $sql->bind_param("sss", $code_pr, $heure_debut, $idcompte);

    if (!$sql->execute()) {
        die('<h3 style="color:red;" align="center">ERREUR</h3>' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
    }
} else {
    if ($pre == 1 && $precheck == 1) {
        $sqlsrt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE presence SET heure_fin=? WHERE user_id=? AND id=?") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        $sqlsrt->bind_param('ss', $heure_fin, $idcompte);
        if (!$sqlsrt->execute()) {
            die('<h3 style="color:red;" align="center">ERREUR</h3>' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to be able to have an id to put in my 'bind_param' .

Comment: You shouldn't space between `- >` on object pointers.

Comment: What is the variable that represent the `id` then? You need to know which ID you are updating, it has nothing to do with `bind_param()` (you just need to add the variable there).

Comment: `die(mysqli_error($mysqli))` should be deleted. It will always be false.

Comment: Thank you for yuor fast anwsers. @Qirel the ID I'm updating, is the one created by my INSERT, but it's auto incremented, that's why I'm having trouble calling it.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL are entirely different pieces of software. I'm removing the former since you seem to be using the mysqli extension.

Comment: You need to somehow pass this id in along with the other request parameters. What is _triggering_ your update functionality - a link, a button in a form, …? In _that_ place you need to pass the id of the record you want to update, to your server-side script.

Comment: @misorude I'm using a form to trigger my update, I'll try in there then. Thank you !

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks for the precision, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the '$conn->lastInsertId()' will help.

```
if (!$sql->execute()) {
    die('<h3 style="color:red;" align="center">ERREUR</h3>' . 
    mysqli_error($mysqli));
}else{
   //Here you can take the ID of the last Insert
   $id = $conn->lastInsertId()
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain *how* it will help

Comment: This captures the ID generated by the insert so it can be used in the `bind_param`, but that part should be shown too.

Comment: They’re not doing an INSERT _followed_ by an UPDATE, they do _either_ an INSERT or an UPDATE. So at the point where the UPDATE is attempted, there _was_ no previous INSERT statement that any id could be gotten from.